# Cannot move folders/files from MTP device to my PC. How should I proceed with fixing this?

Tags: filesystem, android, dolphin, mtp

[image: Move option is disabled.]

I've been facing this issue with MTP devices where I'm not able to move a folder from my Android device to my PC. My PC has Kubuntu v20.04 installed.

Also, I've noticed that when I'm trying to move files like `.srt`, the file manager(`dolphin`) shows me a prompt that it was unable to read the file.
[image: Could not read the file]

Comment: Are you capable of using the command line? Edit your post to add information, do not respond via comments.

Comment: I'm used to the command line but I don't know which info to provide. Could you tell me what I should provide?

Comment: `sudo lshw`, `lsblk -f`, `mount | grep -v /dev/loop`, replug the device and `sudo journalctl--since="-5 minutes"`. Read the `man` pages for each of the above commands.

Comment: @waltinator I ran the commands, and here's what I got: https://pastebin.com/CkzvnYu7

Comment: You only posted the result of `journalctl`, not the other commands.

Comment: Oh, I apologize for that. Here's the new link with all the commands: https://pastebin.com/inSQNv7G

Comment: Read `man securetty pam_securetty`

Comment: I read the manpages for both, but don't know how to proceed. Could you please elaborate a bit? Also, there's nothing as `/etc/securetty` in my Kubuntu partition.